# Get Sentry release version from environment in sentry.properties

Tags: spring-boot, properties-file, sentry

I have a spring boot application and integrating Sentry with it.

I have the following properties in `sentry.properties`

```
release=${SENTRY_RELEASE_VERSION}
dns=${SENTRY_DNS}
stacktrace.app.packages=io.qtalk.datarain
environment=${SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT}
```

Both `dns` and `environment` is able to get its value from the environment except for `release`. The value of `release` is showing as `${SENTRY_RELEASE_VERSION}`

One work around for this is to provide these values via `SentryOptions` but it does not provide any way to set the `stacktrace`.( It does have a workaround by supplying this in the `dns` as query params ).

How can I handle this release issue from `sentry.properties`.

I'm using `sentry-spring-boot-starter` with version `1.7.30`